# Can I include interaction effects in a multilevel random intercept, but fixed slope model?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I am using the `lmer`-command within the `lme4`-package to analyse a fixed intercept, random slope model:

`lmer(IUIF00 ~ SDBC0B_CWC + SDGEMO_CWC + SDAGT1_CWC + SRLR00_CWC + IUPU00_CWC + IUFU00_CWC + SDBCCP + SDGEMOCM + SDAGT1CM + SRLR00CM + IUPU00CM + IUFU00CM + (1|CLASS), data = CDMEdata, na.action=na.exclude, REML = TRUE)`

My data stem from different classrooms (CLASS) and I expect that the outcome variable intergroup friendship (IUIF00) is predicted by two variables on the individual level (IUPU00_CWC, IUFU00_CWC) and SDBCCP (ethnic diversity within the classroom) on the classroom level. As I am exploring the contextual effect of classroom diversity, I cluster-mean centered the predictor variables. All other terms are sociodemographic background variables.

However, from a theoretical perspective, I expect interactions between the three predictors (IUPU00_CWC, IUFU00_CWC, SDBCCP) but I cannot include random slopes, propably because the power is too low.
It appears to me (e.g., after reading "Multilevel Analysis" by Hox et al., 2018), that I can only include cross-level interaction terms AFTER adding random slopes to my model. Is that true or is it also possible to include cross-level interactions in a fixed-slope model? And if so, how do I interpret the output?

Comment: I don't know these R packages well enough to give an answer, but in terms of mathematics yes you can mix and match which parameter are mixed effects.